# Apex Check is Object is enabled

Tags: apex, permissions

We have a managed package and wants to check if the subscriber has enabled Network object in their Org. I try with this 
Schema.sObjectType.Network.isAccessible()
But getting an error if the network object is not enabled.

**Error:** "Missing Organization Feature: NetworksEnabledOnce"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The moment you use a "static reference" to a feature, it becomes a dependency. In other words, your code depends upon Communities being enabled, and therefore the platform requires it to be enabled.

Code like the following automatically causes dependency:

```
Map<String, SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.sobjectType.Network.fields.getMap();
Network[] records = [SELECT Name FROM Network];
Network record = new Network(Name='abc');
```

In order to avoid this, you will need to use "dynamic references", such as the following:

```
if(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey('Network')) {
  sobject[] results = Database.query('select name from network');
  for(sobject result: results) {
    String name = (String)result.get('Name');
    // ... etc ... //
  }
}
```